# Como dispor os campos nas páginas

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio, java-bean

Favor informar se eu precisar melhorar a explicação.

Estou tentando criar um relatório no Jaspersoft Studio composto por três seções: **informação do cliente** (um JavaBean contendo nome, email, data de nascimento, etc.), **endereços do cliente** (uma lista de JavaBeans contendo cada um o nome da rua, número, bairro, etc.) e **pedidos do cliente** (também uma lista de JavaBeans, contendo número do pedido, data, endereço simples, total, etc.).

Entendo que cada uma dessas seções seria um sub-relatório, alimentado por um datasource de JavaBeans distinto.

Não sei bem como distribuí-las em páginas. Por exemplo, a primeira seção (informações do cliente) é pequena e poderia caber em uma página juntamente com a segunda seção (endereços do cliente). Mas os endereços podem eventualmente ocupar mais de uma página, então talvez devessem ser colocados em uma página separada. Não tenho prática suficiente com o JasperReports para decidir, e também não sei como adicionar dois datasources em um mesmo relatório/página, somente em um relatório individual. Por isso estou considerando um sub-relatório por seção.

Também não sei bem em quais bandas devo colocar as seções. Consegui colocar a primeira seção na banda *Title* e a segunda na banda *Summary*, mas não sei bem onde colocar a terceira seção. Colocar duas seções na mesma banda (por exemplo, na *Title*) aparentemente faz uma se sobrepor à outra.

Alguma dica?

[image: Layout proposto para o relatório]

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa leitura da documentação esta [neste link](http://ireport.sourceforge.net/cap5.html), vou copiar a estrutura do report de lá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando estruturo os reports, sigo a seguinte regra:

- Tenho o **master**, que irá inclui alguns dos seguintes: **Title, Header, Page Footer**
- Normalmente tenho várias outras seções, como esta de endereço que você mencionou. Para cada seção dessa eu adiciono **um Subreport** em **uma Detail**
- Os subreports então podem utilizar caso necessário **Column Header e Footer, Detail e Summary**, com isso você pode adicionar cabeçalhos e footers caso seu subreport possua tabelas, e caso ainda você possua subreports estes irão seguir a mesma regra do **master**, um detail para cada subreport.

Em resumo:

- Title: Utilizada apenas para o título do report (eu quase nunca utilizo)
- Page header: Cabeçalho do report (sempre utilizo, para logo da empresa, endereços...)
- Column header: Cabeçalho de uma tabela (a tabela é incluída no Detail)
- Detail: Dados relevantes do relatório (informações do relatório mesmo)
- Column footer: Rodapé da tabela (incluída anteriormente no Detail)
- Page footer: Rodapé da página (normalmente incluo informações como paginação)
- Summary: Área utilizada para somatória de valores (particularmente não utilizo muito, geralmente apresento Details customizadas com somatório por fórmula)

Comment: Olá, seu texto dá a entender que é possível incluir mais de uma banda Detail no mesmo relatório master, isso é possível?

Comment: Olá @Piovezan, sim é perfeitamente possível, eu até recomendo utilizar uma banda de detail por subreport, fica mais organizado.

Comment: Tem um detalhe relacionado às Details, elas são renderizadas dependendo da quantidade de registros passados no datasource, caso você trate múltiplos subreports como minha sugestão, o master deve entender que deve renderizar apenas uma vez, caso contrário você vai ter milhares de Details iguais :)

Comment: Como se informa à master que se deve renderizar uma ou múltiplas vezes?

Comment: Desculpa não ter um exemplo, eu gerava reports na empresa passada, mas acho que passavamos o conteúdo dos subreports como parâmetros para o [JasperFillManager](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html), e o `JRDatasource` utilizando [JRBeanCollectionDatasource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) com uma coleção vazia.

Comment: No nosso caso não passavamos a conexão diretamente ao report por problemas de esgotamento do pool do Tomcat, então pesquisavamos toda a informação antes e passavamos os parâmetros ao report.

Comment: Espero que te ajude :)